# running powershell msi installation script through ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible, windows-installer

I have tried installing a software with powershell via ansible. my power shell script runs correctly in local but when I try through Ansible the installation doesn't run.

Playbook

```
---
- hosts: wins
tasks:
- win_copy:
 src: /etc/ansible/installconnect.ps1
 dest: 'C:/install/33312/Connect'
 remote_src: no

 

- name: winshell
win_shell: C:/install/33312/Connect/installconnect.ps1
become: yes
become_user: Administrator
```

Powershell script (installconnect.ps1)

```
cd \ 

cd C:\hybrinstall\33312\Connect 

.\installer.msi /q /l* logfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need MSIEXEC in there for a start?  I'd also specify a full path to the log file location too.  And perhaps verify the dot notation is working for the path to the MSI?

As an example in your case, it should be:

```
msiexec.exe /i "C:\hybrinstall\33312\Connect\installer.msi" /qn /l*v "C:\Windows\Logs\logfile.txt"
```

However, you might want to refactor your PowerShell script like in this link:
https://www.alkanesolutions.co.uk/2018/07/18/install-and-uninstall-msi-using-powershell/

```
$MSIInstallArguments = @(
    "/i"
    '"C:\hybrinstall\33312\Connect\installer.msi"'
    "/qn"
    "/l*v"
    '"C:\Windows\Logs\logfile.txt"'
)
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $MSIInstallArguments -Wait -NoNewWindow
```